# I want to select last hour results

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ip.IPAddress,
    CONVERT(varchar, dan.AuditDate, 100) AS Date,     
    ip.AuditAction,ip.Username,
    (CASE 
         WHEN CONCAT(k.FirstName, ' ', k.LastName) IS NULL OR CONCAT(k.FirstName, ' ', k.LastName) = ' ' 
             THEN k.Name
             ELSE CONCAT(k.FirstName, ' ', k.LastName)
     END) AS 'Name' 
FROM 
    IPAddress ip
INNER JOIN
    user k ON k.ID = ip.PerformerID
INNER JOIN 
    audit dan ON ip.IPAddress = dan.Value1 
              AND ip.Date = CAST(dan.AuditDate AS Date) 
              AND ip.AuditAction = dan.AuditStr 
              AND ip.PerformerID = dan.PerformerID
INNER JOIN
    LoginMoreOne n ON n.LUsername = ip.Username 
                   AND n.LUsername IS NOT NULL
WHERE 
    LEN(ip.IPAddress) > 8 
    AND dan.AuditDate > DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, DATEADD(mi, 30, GETDATE())), 0)
GROUP BY 
    ip.IPAddress, ip.Date, ip.AuditAction,
    ip.Username, ip.PerformerID,  
    k.FirstName, k.LastName, k.Name,
    CAST(dan.AuditDate AS Date), dan.AuditDate
```

For example if I execute this query at 2.30pm, I want the result from 1pm to 2pm, or if i execute this query at 3.10pm, I want the result from 2pm-3pm, and so on, How do I edit my where statement to be able get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate()), 0)` will gives you date & time at current hour, with minutes, seconds = 0

`-1` gives you the previous hour with 0 mins, 0 secs

```
    AuditDate >= dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
and AuditDate <  dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Comment: I tried this, it is working if I have any questions, I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead

> dan.AuditDate > DATEADD(HOUR, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(mi, 30, GETDATE())), 0)

Use:

```
dan.AuditDate > DATEADD(HH, -1.5, GETDATE()) AND dan.AuditDate <= DATEADD(HH,-0.5, GETDATE())
```

Comment: you have missing parenthesis `)` there. Also the logic is wrong.  For `datediff(HH, -1.5, GETDATE())`  You are trying to find the different in hour between now and  date `-1.5` which does not make sense at all

Comment: Updated parenthesis. But the question asked ```2.30pm, I want the result from 1pm to 2pm```  right ?

Comment: OP stated another example `or if i ...`